# How to send the password reset link via email using queue in laravel 5

Tags: email, laravel-5, queue, laravel-5.1

I am using the ResetsPasswords trait by laravel to implement password reset. What I would like to achieve is to send the email using queue. Digging through the code I found the line below in function postEmail():

```
$response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });
```

Digging further I notice that sendResetLink() function is implemented in a PasswordBroker class which in turn calls the function emailResetLink(). emailResetLink function returns the following:

```
return $this->mailer->send($view, compact('token', 'user'), function ($m) use ($user, $token, $callback) {
            $m->to($user->getEmailForPasswordReset());
```

which I can simply change `mailer->send` to `mailer->queue`. Is they some better way to do it without modifying this non-project file?

Comment: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where the Laravel container comes to the rescue. If you don't like the functionality of a core component then you can go ahead and override it fairly painlessly.

First things first you will need to create your own PasswordBroker:

```
namespace App\Auth\Passwords;

use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker as IlluminatePasswordBroker;

class PasswordBroker extends IlluminatePasswordBroker
{

    public function emailResetLink()
    {
        $view = $this->emailView;

        return $this->mailer->queue($view, compact('token', 'user'), function ($m) use ($user, $token, $callback) {
            $m->to($user->getEmailForPasswordReset());
            if (! is_null($callback)) {
                call_user_func($callback, $m, $user, $token);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Change your namespace to whatever you want if you want to place it elsewhere in your app.

Since the service provider registering the service is a [deferred service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#deferred-providers) you will need to create your own provider to replace it. Probably the easiest way to do this is extend `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider` with something like the following:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker;

class PasswordResetServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider
{

    protected function registerPasswordBroker()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('auth.password', function ($app) {
            $tokens = $app['auth.password.tokens'];

            $users = $app['auth']->driver()->getProvider();

            $view = $app['config']['auth.password.email'];

            return new PasswordBroker(
                $tokens, $users, $app['mailer'], $view
            );
        });
    }

}
```

Finally in your `config/app.php` file remove `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class` and add `App\Providers\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class` to your `'providers'` array.

Laravel will now use your implementation of the PasswordBroker rather than the stock framework one and you don't have to worry about modifying framework code.

Comment: Thanks @marcus.ramsden for your contribution. I have followed your approach but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. I get no error. It seems as though it is still calling `emailResetLink` of the parent class instead of the overwritten one.

Comment: Sorry my mistake on the example, in the registration part of your service provider that should be `$this->app->singleton` instead of `$this->app->bind`. Also the core service provider registering things is a [deferred provider](http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#deferred-providers). I'll get things updated in a moment.

Comment: Thanks again for your input. `$this->app->singleton` isn't doing the trick either. Still calling the parent method.

Comment: With the update, it works beautifully. You've been very helpful @marcus.ramsden

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: In 5.2 I think you would also need to create your own PasswordBrokerManager which would then call your PasswordBroker. Because of the namespace changes you would then override the method like this: `public function emailResetLink(\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword $user, $token, \Closure $callback = null)`

Comment: @JamesF do have an example how this can be done in L5.2 ?

Comment: @michel3vb think this should do it https://gist.github.com/jamesfairhurst/a30f034f6aeef45fe32f17e5588c1adf

Comment: @JamesF Thanks that example fixed my issue!

Comment: Thanks for piping up on that @JamesF :) Do you want to re-produce this as a question specific to Laravel 5.2? I'll make this one specific for 5/5.1 following the broker manager changes.

Answer (score 38):

I know this has been answered but I found another way to queue password reset notification which I found much more simple. I've tested it on **Laravel 5.3 and 6.x**.

By default, password reset notification is implemented by `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword` class. This class is instantiated in your `User` model in `sendPasswordResetNotification` method and passed to `notify` method of `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait.

So, to queue password reset notification you can simply create new `ResetPassword` notification class via `artisan make:notification ResetPassword` and replace it's code with this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;

class ResetPassword extends ResetPasswordNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
}
```

And now just override `sendPasswordResetNotification` method in your `App\User` class:

```
<?php

...
use App\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;
...    

/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

Comment: I think this the best and simple one, this work like a charm in L5.4

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#queueing-notifications

Comment: To specify the queue: `$this->notify((new ResetPasswordNotification($token))->onQueue('queue-name'));`

Comment: @fakemeta Does this also work in Laravel 6? I tried to dig into the reset password code but it's too complex for my little brain

Comment: @Agil You might have found this out already. I tested it and it does indeed work on Laravel 6.

Comment: it's working in laravel 8 breeze authentication, it's the same as implementing email verification, thanks

Comment: Just tried, works as explained even in Laravel 8 with Breeze authentication!

Answer (score 1):

In case you get "Call to a member function onQueue() on null" after trying to specify queue fakemeta's solution just specify the the queue you are targeting in the constructor of your class.

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ResetPasswordNotification extends ResetPassword implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->queue = "authentication";
    }
}
```

then use the notification facade  to send your mail in the overriding method. The notify method also works

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\ResetPasswordNotification;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        // either of the two work
        // $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
        \Notification::send($this, new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```