# How to send the password reset link via email using queue in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I am trying to use the queue when resetting passwords in Laravel 5.2 using [How to send the password reset link via email using queue in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409236/how-to-send-the-password-reset-link-via-email-using-queue-in-laravel-5) however I am getting the following error:

ReflectionException in Container.php line 735:
Class auth.password.tokens does not exist

How do I get around this?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution on GitHub [Password Reset Queue Email](https://gist.github.com/jamesfairhurst/a30f034f6aeef45fe32f17e5588c1adf). This solution includes PasswordBrokerManager. Additionally the default provider in config\app.php is replaced by the new one App\Providers\PasswordResetServiceProvider.php