# Sending ResetPassword notification using queue in Laravel 6 - error property 'view'

Tags: notifications, queue, laravel-6

I want to override default notifications for password reset and email verification in laravel 6 to use queue in a simplest way as possible. So I add methods in **User.php** model:

```
use App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification;
use App\Notifications\EmailVerificationNotification;
...
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}

public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new EmailVerificationNotification);
}
```

and create new notifications

**ResetPasswordNotification**

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;

class ResetPasswordNotification extends ResetPassword implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

}
```

**EmailVerificationNotification**

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;

class EmailVerificationNotification extends VerifyEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

}
```

Now email verification is sending queued, but in url as a host name is generating http://localhost/... In default notification it is generated correctly, the same one like a domain name in browser (without changing it in .env file).

The second problem is with password reset notification, which is not sending at all. It gives me an error

```
Trying to get property 'view' of non-object at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php:92
```

and I don't understand why it is happening and don't working as expected.

Searching the problem I even found this ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409236/how-to-send-the-password-reset-link-via-email-using-queue-in-laravel-5)) where fakemeta mention about it that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. First, when using queue, in my case I am running artisan queue:work with supervisor daemon, jobs are running under the console, so there is no SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] var available which mean than this value must be read from .env file. Second, when You change code overriding methods like I did, you must restart this queue:work to re-read changes. So those were my main problems.